# Rails 3 + jQuery: loading a div on interval isn't working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

My Rails app needs to retrieve an updated count from the server every minute.

I'm attempting to have a javascript timer reload the specific div where I display this count.

```
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js", "application", "refresh-timer" %>
```

You'll notice at the end I include my refresh-timer.js, which is just a single call:

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
setInterval(function(){ $('refreshable').load('/refreshable'); }, 3000);})
```

That 'refreshable' object corresponds to this in my status.html.erb view:

```
<div class="main">
   <div id="refreshable">
       <%= render :partial => 'refreshable' %>
   </div>
```

Yes, there's more in the "main" div, but it's the div#refreshable that's of interest.

Since the javascript is loading /refreshable, in my routes.rb I created a match:

```
  match "refreshable" => "events#refreshable"
```

While I doubt that's strictly the right thing to do here, I'm trying to simplify things to find why the javascript timer isn't calling the action.

For a test that my jQuery was set up right, I replaced the innards of the setInterval function with a call to alert.  That worked fine: every three seconds the alert popped up.
I've also examined the page in Safari's development tools -- there are no javascript errors being reported, no extraneous html coding errors -- it's all very clean (and pretty simplified as I tried to figure this out).

For now, as a fallback, I've added the meta call for an http-refresh every 10 seconds. Which allows me to watch in my development.log that this is the only call coming from the browser to the app.

I'd love troubleshooting tips for javascript/jQuery more than anything else.  My current attempts to bugger things ups just to get something to fail and produce evidence of where things are going wrong also don't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is wrong. Change this:

```
$('refreshable')
```

To this:

```
$('#refreshable')
```

Comment: I also want to point out that your selector was not returning any errors because $('refreshable') is in fact a legal selector -- it's looking for "refreshable" tags, just as $('a') or $('input') would look for "a" or "input" tags.

Comment: I also want to add that the method you outlined for debugging (trying to narrow the problem down to a simple test case, temporarily replacing code to locate the exact place it breaks down, and using your browser inspector tools) is exactly the right way to approach this sort of problem. This just happened to be a very tricky one -- I've been doing jQuery for a while and I almost didn't even spot the bug. It's the kind of typo anyone might make and then spend an hour scratching their head about.

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  For the love of a pound sign!